# How to create moodle local plugin

Tags: moodle

I'm creating a custom moodle local plugin, but I'm not finding any help regarding this.
Can someone help and give me general layout of the local plugin?

I'm new in moodle.

Comment: Visit this link for detailed document about local plugin [http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins)

Comment: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=265196

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create local plugin you can follow following folder structure according to Moodle documentation (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins)-

```
local/
     yourplugin/
       db/
         access.php
         install.php
         install.xml
       lang/
         en/
           yourplugin.php
       index.php
       settings.php
       version.php
```

Comment: i want customize lesson activity . is it ok to use local plugin?